# Configure Git to use Beyond Compare for image diff

Tags: windows, images, git, version-control, beyondcompare

Because we work with a number of sprites, the kind of [specialised diff views](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php?zz=moreinfo_viewers) provided by [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) would be ideal to see which one of 2 versions I'm after when conflicts arise.

I've already configured Git to use Beyond Compare as my primary diff and merge tool [as described in their integration guide](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#tortoisesvn) — it specifically goes into [how to configure TortoiseSVN to use it for images](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#tortoisesvn), and I've found [these](http://lars-tesmer.com/blog/2010/09/20/git---how-to-get-better-diffs-for-images/) [articles](http://www.akikoskinen.info/image-diffs-with-git/) talking about `.gitattributes` in general and how to script interactions from a *nix shell — but it's not obvious to me how I can use the advice provided by these guides to make a simple change that would say "use the default diff & merge bindings for files determined to be images, too".

For the record, I'm doing all this on Windows :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Using Beyond Compare with Version Control Systems - Git for Windows](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#gitwindows):

> Note:  If you use the Git for Windows' Bash Command Prompt instead of
>   the default Windows Command Prompt, you need to escape the $ character
>   with .
>
> For Git 1.7.6 and newer, edit the global config file to set the path
>
> #### Diff
>
> At a Windows command prompt enter the commands:
>
> ```
> git config --global diff.tool bc3
> git config --global difftool.bc3.path "c:/program files/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe"
> ```
>
> To launch a diff with BC3, use the command "git difftool foofile.txt".
>
> #### 3-way Merge (v3 Pro)
>
> At a Windows command prompt, enter the commands:
>
> ```
> git config --global merge.tool bc3
> git config --global mergetool.bc3.path "c:/program files/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe"
> ```
>
> Use `git merge` for the regular merge and `git mergetool` for the
>   Beyond Compared based merge.

This worked fine with **BCompare-3.3.8.16340.exe** and **Git-1.8.4-preview20130916.exe**:

```
C:\su-q>git difftool "HEAD^"

Viewing: 'README'
Launch 'bc3' [Y/n]:

Viewing: 'bag_frame.gif'
Launch 'bc3' [Y/n]:
```